Differential of non-Euclidean distance function
For a fixed value of $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ be the real vector space of all real polynomials of degree $< k$. Fix $k$ distinct values $x_1 < \ldots < x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and for every $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ let $\mathbf{\hat{y}} \in P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ be the Lagrange polynomial that interpolates the pairs $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_k,y_k)$.
Let $I$ be the real closed interval $[x_1, x_k]$. For $f$ ranging on $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ the following
$$||f||_{\infty} = \sum_{i=0}^{k} \sup_{x_0 \in I} \Big| \frac{d^i}{d^ix}f(x_0) \Big|$$
is a norm and gives to $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ the structure of Banach space. Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be fixed. I know that $||\mathbf{\hat{x}}-\mathbf{\hat{\mu}} ||_{\infty}$ is a continuous function of $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ (w.r.t. Euclidean topology).
Does it have a differential $D_{\mathbf{\mu}}: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ at point $\mathbf{\mu} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ ? How could it be represented by a $k\times k$ real matrix?

try $k=2$   and write out everything, see what happens

Thanks @WillJagy for the advice. The fact that such natural norm for functions is not differentiable makes me want to look for another functional norm that is instead differentiable.

For $k = 2$, $P^{2}[\mathbb{R}] = \{ax+b : (a, b) \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Let $I = [x_1, x_2]$.
$$||ax+b||_{\infty} = a + \max \{|ax_1+b|, |ax_2+b|\}$$
is a norm and gives to $P^{k}[\mathbb{R}]$ the structure of Banach space. Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be fixed. I know that $||\mathbf{\hat{x}}-\mathbf{\hat{\mu}} ||_{\infty}$ is a continuous function of $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ (w.r.t. Euclidean topology).
For each fixed $\mu \in \mathbf{R}^2$, the map that associates $\mathbf{y} = (y_1,y_2)$ to $||\mathbf{\hat{y}}-\mathbf{\hat{\mu}} ||_{\infty}$ is not differentiable at infinitely many points.
